# How to make a $\rho$-shaped graph for various lists of numbers as nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is derived from this [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469190), where @marmot solved it nicely.  However, that solution assumes the cycle will always have a number of nodes more or less like 11.  When you apply that solution to a cycle with, say, 4 nodes, the cycle looks more like a square.

How could we change those arrows to present themselves more like a circle?  Ideally it would look like an ellipse with radii as near as possible to the $rho$ letter, but a circle would do just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node[circle,minimum width=7cm] (circ) {};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {32,25,50,17}
{\node  (cn\Y) at ({-(\Y-2.5)*360/4}:3.5) {$\X$}; }
\foreach \Y [remember=\Y as \LastY (initially 4)]in {1,...,4}
{\draw[-latex,shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt] (cn\LastY) to[bend left=10] (cn\Y);}

\begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
  every node/.append style={on chain,,xshift=-{cot(76)*1.5cm}},
  every join/.style=latex-]
\node[below=of cn4] (n0) {$36$};
\draw[latex-] (cn4) -- (n0);
\node[join] (n6) {$9$};
\node[join] (n5) {$1$};
\node[join] (n4) {$24$};
\node[join] (n3) {$4$};
\node[join] (n2) {$46$};
\node[join] (n1) {$12$};
\node[join] (n0) {$2$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `[bend left=30]` instead of `[bend left=10]` it looks much better. One can compute the "optimal" bend or draw the arcs differently. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It's true that [benf left=30] makes it a lot better, but if we take [Zarko's solution](https://imgur.com/a/JbT6V7R) from the other question, we can see that it is able to draw a circle quite nicely, though the tail doesn't fit in very well.  It didn't make it [yet] to change the slope of the tail so that it gets out of the circle.  I don't think the 76-degree slope will survive on this case.  (Unless you apply your magic again!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. I did not think about arbitrary numbers of nodes, but I should. Here is a version that draws the connections on a precise circle. (In Zarko's nice answer there are still parameters that need to be adjusted by hand. Yet it is true that for long arcs `arc`s tend to look better than `bend left`.) The disadvantage is that it takes a while to compile.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,calc,intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{3.5}
\path[name path=big circle] (0,0) circle (\Radius cm);
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {32,25,50,17}
{\node[name path global=\Y-circ,inner sep=4pt,circle]  (cn\Y) at 
({-(\Y-2.5)*360/4}:\Radius) {$\X$}; }
\foreach \Y [remember=\Y as \LastY (initially 4)]in {1,...,4}
{
\path[name intersections={of=big circle and \LastY-circ,by={aux0,aux2},sort
by=big circle},
name intersections={of=big circle and \Y-circ,by={aux1,aux3},sort
by=big circle}];
\draw[-latex] 
let \p1=($(aux0)-(0,0)$),\p2=($(aux3)-(0,0)$),
\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
\n3={(ifthenelse(\n2<\n1,\n2,\n2-360)} in 
(aux0) arc(\n1:\n3:\Radius);
}

\begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
  every node/.append style={on chain,,xshift=-{cot(76)*1.5cm}},
  every join/.style=latex-]
\node[below=of cn4] (n0) {$36$};
\draw[latex-] (cn4) -- (n0);
\node[join] (n6) {$9$};
\node[join] (n5) {$1$};
\node[join] (n4) {$24$};
\node[join] (n3) {$4$};
\node[join] (n2) {$46$};
\node[join] (n1) {$12$};
\node[join] (n0) {$2$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively one can find approximate values to be fed into bend left. The following code compiles much faster but not yield exact circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{3.5}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {32,25,50,17}
{\node[inner sep=4pt,circle]  (cn\Y) at 
({-(\Y-2.5)*360/4}:\Radius) {$\X$}; }
\foreach \Y [remember=\Y as \LastY (initially 4)]in {1,...,4}
{
\path (cn\LastY) -- (cn\Y) coordinate[pos=0](aux0) coordinate[pos=1](aux1);
\draw[-latex] 
let \p1=($(aux0)-(0,0)$),\p2=($(aux1)-(0,0)$),
\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
\n3={0.45*(\n1-ifthenelse(\n2<\n1,\n2,\n2-360)} in 
(cn\LastY) to[bend left=\n3] (cn\Y);
}

\begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
  every node/.append style={on chain,,xshift=-{cot(76)*1.5cm}},
  every join/.style=latex-]
\node[below=of cn4] (n0) {$36$};
\draw[latex-] (cn4) -- (n0);
\node[join] (n6) {$9$};
\node[join] (n5) {$1$};
\node[join] (n4) {$24$};
\node[join] (n3) {$4$};
\node[join] (n2) {$46$};
\node[join] (n1) {$12$};
\node[join] (n0) {$2$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The compilation is definitely acceptable.  I think your first version is great.  However, when I consider another sequence of numbers --- a bit smaller ---, the graph is still nice, but the tail ended up on the right side, making the rho letter show up [backwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469243).